# Why does my fast exponentiation algorithm give me a 'cannot find symbol' error in the parameter of a lambda?

Tags: java, algorithm, lambda, parameters, compiler-errors

**Background/Goal I am trying to accomplish:**

I am attempting to implement the fast exponentiation algorithm in Java from scratch (as practice).  The algorithm is as follows (explanation taken from johndcook.com):

Input: base *b*, exponent *n*.

Write the exponent n in binary. Read the binary representation from left to right, starting with the second bit from the left. Start with the number a, and every time you read a 0 bit, square what you’ve got. Every time you read a 1 bit, square what you’ve got and multiply by a. It follows that an can be computed using no more than 2 log2(n) multiplications.

I am not looking for a better way to implement this algorithm, but rather why I am getting this particular error.

**What the problem is**

I tried to implement this algorithm using a recursive lambda in Java, and when I went to run the program, I got the following errors:

> Main.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
> exponentiator = (int runningResult, int binLength, int binInt, int expBase) -> {
>                                                                ^
> ```
>
> Main.java:11: error: lambda expression not expected here
>
> ```
> exponentiator = (int runningResult, int binLength, int binInt, int expBase) -> {
> ^
> ```
>
> Main.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
> exponentiator(b, length, nBinInt, b);
> ^
> ```

I have no explanation for these errors, can anyone help me out?

**Code:**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    fastExp(2, 13);
  }
  //This is the algorithm itself
  public static int fastExp(int b, int n) {
    //converts n (b^n) to binary for algorithm
    String nBinStr = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    int nBinInt = Integer.parseInt(nBinStr);
    int length = String.valueOf(nBinInt).length();
    exponentiator = (int runningResult, int binLength, int binInt, int expBase) -> {
      int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(binInt).substring(1, 2));
      if(binLength = 0){
        return runningResult;
      }
      else if(firstDigit = 0){
        exponentiator((runningResult * runningResult), (binLength - 1), (binInt % (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(binInt))), expBase);
      }
      else {
      exponentiator((runningResult * runningResult * base), (binLength - 1), (binInt % (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(binInt))), expBase);
      }
    };
    exponentiator(b, length, nBinInt, b);
  }
}
```

https://repl.it/@Jodastt/Fast-Exponentiation

Comment: Labdas can't reference themself.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn what would be a legal alternative?

Comment: Just use a regular method.

Comment: Pass the lambda as parameter.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn as a parameter of what?

Comment: As parameter of the lambda.

Comment: What is `exponentiator`supposed to be? If it's a method, that's not how methods are declared in Java. If it's a variable, it needs to be declared, with a type. Where's the type of that variable defined?

Comment: @JBNizet it's a lambda, a friend told me that's how they're defined in Java (I've only been using it for ~2 weeks)

Comment: There is no such thing as inline lambdas without a type in Java. Java is not JavaScript. In Java, you would need something like `Function<Integer, Integer> f = x -> x + 1;` And once you have that variable, of type Function<Integer, Integer>, you would invoked using `Integer b = f.apply(42);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem you have is that your lambda doesn't have a type. You need to give it one. I am not aware of any types in `java.util.function` that can represent a function taking 4 parameters, so you probably need to declare this type yourself.

The other major problem is that you are using the variable `exponentiator` inside its declaration, which is invalid. To work around this, you need to add a fifth parameter to your lambda, to which the lambda itself will be passed. You will then replace the recursive calls with calls to this parameter.

Let's declare the type to represent this lambda first.

```
interface IntQuadRecursiveFunction {
    int apply(int a, int b, int c, int d, IntQuadRecursiveFunction f);
}
```

And then `exponentiator` can be redeclared like so:

```
// note the type and extra parameter "f"
IntQuadRecursiveFunction exponentiator = (runningResult, binLength, binInt, expBase, f) -> {
   int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(binInt).substring(1, 2));
   if (binLength == 0) { // It's "==", not "="
       return runningResult;
   } else if (firstDigit == 0) {
        // note the word "return", which you were missing
        // also the extra argument "f"
       return f.apply((runningResult * runningResult), (binLength - 1), (binInt % (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(binInt))), expBase, f);
   } else {
       // should be "expBase", not "base"
       return f.apply((runningResult * runningResult * expBase), (binLength - 1), (binInt % (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(binInt))), expBase, f);
   }
};
```

usage:

```
// you are missing a return in "fastExp" as well
return exponentiator.apply(b, length, nBinInt, b, exponentiator); // note the last argument
```

---

To be honest, if I were you I would just save all this trouble and write a normal method instead:

```
public static int fastExp(int b, int n) {
    //converts n (b^n) to binary for algorithm
    String nBinStr = Integer.toBinaryString(n);
    int nBinInt = Integer.parseInt(nBinStr);
    int length = String.valueOf(nBinInt).length();
    return exponentiator(b, length, nBinInt, b);
}

private static int exponentiator(int runningResult, int binLength, int binInt, int expBase) {
    int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(binInt).substring(1, 2));
    if (binLength == 0) { 
        return runningResult;
    } else if (firstDigit == 0) {
        return exponentiator((runningResult * runningResult), (binLength - 1), (binInt % (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(binInt))), expBase);
    } else {
        return exponentiator((runningResult * runningResult * expBase), (binLength - 1), (binInt % (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(binInt))), expBase);
    }
}
```